# if bn is bounded and non-negative, ∑an is convergent, then ∑anbn convergent (?)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

If $\sum a_n$ is convergent and $b_n$ is bounded sequence of non-negative numbers then $\sum a_nb_n$ is convergent.
I know the statement is false and I found the following counter example: 
Let $\sum a_n = 1 - 1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3} ...$ 
$b_n = \begin{cases} 1 & n\enspace is \enspace odd\\ 0 & otherwise \end{cases}$
Therfore:
$\sum a_n b_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and of course divergent.

But when I approached this problem on the first time, I thought I managed to prove that the statement is true and until now I couldn't find what is wrong with the proof I wrote, I will appreciate any help.

Proof: 
Suppose $\sum a_n$ is convergent, therfore by Cauchy's convergence test 
For every $\epsilon > 0 $ there is a natural number N such that : 
$|a_{n+1} + a_{n+2} + \ . \ . \ . \ +a_{n+p}| < \epsilon$ 
holds for all n > N and all p ≥ 1 
$b_n$ is bounded and non-negative,therefore there exists a real number M > 0 such that, $b_n \leq M$ for all positive integers n. 
Let $\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon}{Mp} > 0$ 
There exists a natural number N such that: 
$|a_{n+1} + a_{n+2} + \ . \ . \ . \ +a_{n+p}| < \frac{\epsilon}{Mp}$ 
holds for all n > N and all p ≥ 1 
$\iff Mp|a_{n+1} + a_{n+2} + \ . \ . \ . \ +a_{n+p}| < \epsilon \iff |Ma_{n+1} + Ma_{n+2} + \ . \ . \ . \ +Ma_{n+p}| < \epsilon$ 
But
$|a_{n+1}b_{n+1} + a_{n+2}b_{n+2} + \ . \ . \ . \ +a_{n+p}b_{n+p}| \leq|Ma_{n+1} + Ma_{n+2} + \ . \ . \ . \ +Ma_{n+p}| < \epsilon$

I couldn't find what I did wrong here and I will be grateful for any insights.

Comment: How do you infer $|a_{n+1}b_{n+1}+\ldots+a_{n+p}b_{n+p}|\le |Ma_{n+1}+\ldots+Ma_{n+p}|$? The triangle inequality only implies that $|a_{n+1}b_{n+1}+\ldots+a_{n+p}b_{n+p}|\le |Ma_{n+1}|+\ldots+|Ma_{n+p}|$

Comment: Gotcha,
So probably this was my wrong move,
If we had the assumption that $a_n \geq 0$ then this proof was okay, right?

Comment: Are you sure the statement wasn't $b_n\ge0$ and $B_n=\sum_{k=1}^nb_k$ bounded? The statement would then hold.

Comment: @Invisible
Yes I am sure, the statement assumptions are that $b_n$ is bounded sequence and that it is consisted of non-negative numbers (i.e. $b_n \geq 0$ for every integer n).

Comment: @Yarin: Yes, if $a_n\ge 0$, that means $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent. Say it converges to $\alpha$; if $0\le b_n\le M$ for all $n$, then $\sum a_nb_n\le M\alpha$ is convergent. Your proof seems fine too in that case.